# Valgrind is not showing line numbers

Tags: fortran, numbers, version, valgrind, flags

My fortran code gets failed if I run it without debugger. But if I use valgrind while running it runs. Surely, a case of memory issue. I thought to debug the code using valgrind and it does contain errors like...

```
==988381==    at 0x15EA7C: __nautilus_main_MOD_init_reaction_rates (in /home/seps/Desktop/softwares/DNautilus_spin/bin/dnautilus_spin)
==988381==    by 0x16AD99: __nautilus_main_MOD_initialisation (in /home/seps/Desktop/softwares/DNautilus_spin/bin/dnautilus_spin)
==988381==    by 0x10B44C: MAIN__ (in /home/seps/Desktop/softwares/DNautilus_spin/bin/dnautilus_spin)
==988381==    by 0x10B30E: main (in /home/seps/Desktop/softwares/DNautilus_spin/bin/dnautilus_spin)
==988381==  Address 0x4fb7c98 is 8 bytes before a block of size 20,864 alloc'd
==988381==    at 0x483C855: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==988381==    by 0x150140: __global_variables_MOD_initialize_global_arrays (in /home/seps/Desktop/softwares/DNautilus_spin/bin/dnautilus_spin)
==988381==    by 0x16AD2B: __nautilus_main_MOD_initialisation (in /home/seps/Desktop/softwares/DNautilus_spin/bin/dnautilus_spin)
==988381==    by 0x10B44C: MAIN__ (in /home/seps/Desktop/softwares/DNautilus_spin/bin/dnautilus_spin)
==988381==    by 0x10B30E: main (in /home/seps/Desktop/softwares/DNautilus_spin/bin/dnautilus_spin)
```

But valgrind is not showing any line numbers. I compiled the code using flags like -g3, -g, -fbacktrace, -o0. Even then, valgrind is not showing line numbers.

I tried changing the flags except -g3 while compiling the code. I tried different valgrind versions like valgrind-3.19.0, valgrind-3.20.0. These I did based on the suggestions from web search.

All I want is to get line numbers so that I can proceed further. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea. Your best hope is to use vgdb (run valgrind with --vgdb-error=0 then follow the instructions in a separate terminal).

Comment: One generally inserts the code in question, and it is the requirement of the fortran stack. In any case I assume -g3 is a gfortran flag. In there an equivalent of -CB or -check bounds ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are using gfortran, then compile your code with at least `-fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero -Wall`.  Fix all warnings.